# Support native recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion

I read an article about recursion in Haskell that says:

> But the lambda calculus does not appear on the surface to have any
>   means of recursion, because of the anonymity of expressions. How do
>   you call something without a name? Being able to write recursive
>   functions, though, is essential to Turing completeness. We use a
>   combinator – known as the Y combinator or fixed-point combinator – to
>   write recursive functions in the lambda calculus. Haskell has native
>   recursion ability based on the same principle as the Y combinator.

What does native recursion mean?

Consider following code snippet:

```
applyTimes :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> (b -> b) -> b -> b
applyTimes 0 f b = b
applyTimes n f b = f (applyTimes (n-1) f b)
```

The above code does not conform `Y combinator` principle, because `applyTimes` is called in function body itself and it does not defined before.
Please proof my answer, if I wrong.

Comment: Link to the article?

Comment: The article is from this book http://haskellbook.com/.

Comment: I copied the article, please consider it.

Comment: "Haskell has native recursion ability" seems to be the key bit.

Answer (score 4):

"Native recursion" means the language itself supports recursive definitions. Unlike the bare-bones lambda calculus, where all terms are anonymous, Haskell does have a way to name expressions; and moreover when giving a definition for a name, you may use that name itself. You observed this yourself: while defining `applyTimes` you used the name `applyTimes`, and consequently took advantage of Haskell's native support for recursion.

You could also imagine a different language which supported named expressions but not recursion; indeed many functional languages have distinguished "letrec" and "let" forms for definitions which are recursive and which are not recursive, respectively. In such a language, your definition for `applyTimes` would be rejected if it used the "let" form, and accepted if it used the "letrec" form.

Comment: Could you please explain "letrec" and "let"?

Answer (score 2):

“Native recursion” just means that Haskell has recursion as a “native” (built-in) language feature, in the form of recursive definitions and `let` bindings:

```
-- Recursive definition
map f (x : xs) = f x : map f xs
                       ---
map _ [] = []

-- Recursive “let” binding
main = let ones = 1 : ones in print (take 10 ones)
                      ----
```

Internally, the compiler *could* rewrite these using a fixed-point combinator (`fix`), for example as a simplification before typechecking, but I’m not aware if it actually does this.

```
map f xs = let
  map' k (x : xs) = f x : k xs
  map' _ [] = []
  in fix map' xs

main = let
  ones = fix ones'
  ones' k = 1 : k
  in print (take 10 ones)
```

In Haskell, the fixed-point combinator is implemented using the native support for recursive bindings:

```
-- Naïve implementation
fix f = f (fix f)

-- Optimisation to improve sharing
fix f = let x = f x in x
```

And any recursive function can be expressed using `fix`:

```
applyTimes :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> (b -> b) -> b -> b
applyTimes 0 f b = b
applyTimes n f b = f (applyTimes (n-1) f b)

applyTimes n f b = let
  applyTimes' _ 0 = b
  applyTimes' k n = f (k (n - 1))
  in fix applyTimes' n
```

Note that *without* native recursion, the Y combinator `\ f -> (\ x -> f (x x)) (\ x -> f (x x))` can’t be expressed in simply typed lambda calculus because there is no type for `x` that would allow it to be a function taking `x` as an argument. Specifically, it fails the “occurs check”: if `x` is a function then it must have a type of the form `a -> b`, but if `x` is passed as an argument to `x` then it must have the type `a`. Clearly `a` cannot equal `a -> b` because `a` occurs in `a -> b`, so it would expand infinitely: `a -> b`, `(a -> b) -> b`, `((a -> b) -> b) -> b`, and so on.

While Haskell’s type system is more powerful than STLC, it’s typical for typed functional languages to offer recursion as a primitive part of the language rather than with a fixed-point combinator.

Comment: "Internally, the compiler could rewrite these using a fixed-point combinator (`fix`), for example as a simplification before typechecking, but I’m not aware if it actually does this." That would be a considerable *complexification*, and I have no idea how it would work. Certainly, `let` cannot always be translated to lambda in *Haskell*, although it's likely possible in the impredicative System FC of GHC Core. GHC certainly doesn't perform such a translation anywhere; it uses `let` and `letrec` forms up until code generation.

Comment: Could you explain more about `let bindings`?

Answer (score 1):

> The above code does not conform to the `Y combinator` principle, because applyTimes is called in function body itself and it does not defined before.

What about something like this?

```
fix :: (a -> a) -> a
fix f = f (fix f)

applyTimes :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> (b -> b) -> b -> b
applyTimes n f b = fix go n where

  go rec n = if n == 0 then b
             else f (rec (n - 1))
```